# MySQL aes_decrypt on Ubuntu 20.04 returns hex data

Tags: mysql

I recently installed Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on my 64 bit laptop.

I also installed MySQL. Until now everything on MySQL was working well. However I am having problems with AES_ENCRYPT and AES_DECRYPT. I am using the same code I was using on MySQL under Windows 10 where it was all working perfectly. However on Ubuntu 20.04 when I attempt to decrypt the data I just get a hex string.

```
The mysql table was created using

create table my_encrypted_control (
    encrypted_data  varbinary(4096) not null
);

The insert is as follows

insert into my_encrypted_control ( encrypted_data )
values ( aes_encrypt('TEST STRING','funky-boy') );

The select to retrieve and decrypt the data is

select aes_decrypt(encrypted_data,'funky-boy') from my_encrypted_control;

look at the hex data in the result

mysql> select aes_decrypt(encrypted_data,'funky-boy') from my_encrypted_control;
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| aes_decrypt(encrypted_data,'funky-boy')                                          |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 0x5445535420535452494E47                                                         |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Just for interest sake I ran an unecrypted select as follows:

```
mysql> select * from my_encrypted_control;
+------------------------------------+
| encrypted_data                     |
+------------------------------------+
| 0xB5300A75B6BDE6C6F3F4E39B76AEF045 |
+------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Notice the hex/binary data !

How can I encrypt and decrypt data using MySQL under Ubuntu?

Comment: Of note, `0x5445535420535452494E47` translates to `TEST STRING`. Is `binary-as-hex` set in your `mysql.cnf`?

Comment: ==> mysql.cnf <==
[mysql]

==> mysqldump.cnf <==
[mysqldump]
quick
quote-names
max_allowed_packet = 16M